# To get value from database in a DIV (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the script i am using to get the value after a time interval from my database

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        j(".refreshMe").everyTime(10000,function(i){
            j.ajax({
              url: "refresh-me.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j(".refreshMe").html(html);
              }
            })
        })
    });
   j('.refreshMe').css();
});



</script>
```

refresh-me.php code:

```
<?
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE project_id="xyz123" ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1  ';

mysql_select_db('finaltest');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $value=$row['value'] ;

} 
mysql_close($conn);
echo $value;
?>
```

This script works however when i try to apply this in my admin panel that i have design it doesnt work.

I want this Script to display the value from the database instead of 57 in the below code what should i do:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="stat-boxes widget-body">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart black"></span>
                    <h3 class="ticker--one">57</h3>
                    <i>SoilMoisture</i>

                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you see any error on console?

Comment: i dont get any error my admin page gets displayed as it is

Comment: You should consider using PDO or at the very least mysqli. The mysql_* family of functions have been deprecated for a very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
j(".refreshMe").html(html);
```

The server response is inserted into element with the refreshMe class. If you would like the response to be inserted elsewhere, adjust j(".refreshMe"), so it will insert the response where you'd want it to go. To have it in ticker--one, instead use:

```
j(".ticker--one").html(html);
```

Comment: i am new to this where i should add j(".refreshMe").html(html); in the div tag

Comment: Javascript / jQuery will update your elements, regardless of the position of the script.

j(".refreshMe").html(html); should be where it is right now. You'd only want to adjust the selector so that the right element is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Update your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        j(".refreshMe").everyTime(10000,function(i){
            j.ajax({
              url: "refresh-me.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j("h3.ticker--one").html(html);
              }
            })
        })
    });
   j('.refreshMe').css();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where i should add the script at the start or in the div tag